# Passing variable from execute shell to email-ext in Jenkins using pre-mail scipt

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I need to use the variable which i have crated in the execute shell in the mail notification. I dont have envinject plugin, can you suggest some other solution.. I found one of the solution as using the pre-mail script to load the property file, before sending mail. But i dont have idea for the groovy script. Can anyone please suggest to resolve it. Thanks in advance

I have tried the below one, but i got error.

String fileContents = new File("file.txt").text msg.setText(fileContents,"UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can send the email from Shell itself with following code

```
echo "Hello" | sendmail -f customer1@gmail.com customer2@gmail.com


echo "Test" | mail -a "From: no-reply <XXX> <xyzuser>@gmail.com" \
                   -a "Subject: This is a test" \
                   -a "X-Custom-Header: yes" Notify@gmail.com
```